# Find angle face under mouse pointer in Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a projector component and I need to find the angle that projected texture falls at to exclude the projecting on vertical faces.

My projector is under the mouse pointer and works ok when it is over an horizontal face:

[image: projector texture over a horizontal face]

I would like the projector to switch off on vertical faces to avoid this bad effect:

[image: projector texture over a vertical face]

If possible, I would like to do it in the shader code to avoid the vertical projected image even if the cursor is located on the corners of an horizontal face and a part "goes out" on vertical face.

I found this solution in C#:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(MouseRay,out hitInfo)){

    if(hitInfo.normal.y>0) {
        // draw
    } else {
        // not draw
    }
}
```

But only it works on curved surfaces and not, for example, on the face cubes.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Normally they would use an image on a quad using TGA transparency, which rotates itself to the face that the middle of the object is aligned to, using ray to find the vertex and making it's absolute normal.

Other ways of doing it would be quite tricky, perhaps using decals... If you did it using a shader, it would take so much time... it's a case of problem solving not being ordered in order of importance for fast development. Technically you can project a volumetric texture on top of whatever object you are using... that way you can add your barred circle projected from a point in space towards the object, as a mathematical formula, it takes a while to do, check out volumetric textures, i have written some and in your case it needs the mouse pos sent to texture and maths to add transparent zone and red zone to texture. takes all day.

It's fine to have a flat circle that flips around when you change the pointer onto a different face, it will just look like a physical card and it's much easier to code, 10 minutes instead of many hours.